# Managing multiple low-quality wifi connections, dynamically switching to whichever has the best quality

Tags: networking, wifi

Suppose you need to connect to the internet, and have 3 unstable/low-quality wifi connections available to you. Is there some sort of software that automatically connects to whichever source is more stable/high-quality, or simultaneously connects to all three and switches according to stability/quality?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.